# Should I build a model for all route pairs or just one?

Tags: r, machine-learning, prediction

I have to create a ML model to predict which routes will be used more frequently based on 3 datasets.

The datasets are:

- Bases: The bases that the routes beginning from and end in. The most important now is that they have a unique ID. There are around 200 bases. Think of them like addresses in a city.
- Weather: The weather, measured at a certain time interval for the course of the whole experiment. Certain features might affect customer preference to travel a route
- Travels: The actual travels or "transactions" that involve an agent_id and a source-destionation base pair with timestamps for departure and arrival

I'm not expecting a precise answer but rather an approach. There are very frequently used routes (from base 134 to 789 for example) and routes that have 0 transactions. Customers travel between these routes and they use bases far more often which are relatively close to each other and are more available to them. Combining every base pair makes a lot of routes.

My question is if I want to create my model based on the weather data and a certain route to predict the frequency of that route, should I create a model for *each* route or is there some kind of generalized model that could be implemented here?